# How to get thumbnail from a wordpress database into an external page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation. What i'd like to do is call data directly from the wordpress tables in the database and display them on some other non-wordpress pages.

At the moment i'm successfully pulling in the three most recent posts from the **wp_posts** table. I can't however see in the schema where the post thumbnail (or featured image) are stored.

How can I get either the featured image, or thumbnail? (either will do!)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its all in you wp_postmeta table

will query the thumbnail ID of a certain post ID (you need to have your post IDs).

```
SELECT * FROM 'tksql_postmeta' WHERE post_id=1 AND meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

Imagine the returned thumb id is : 600

```
SELECT * FROM 'tksql_postmeta' WHERE post_id=600
```

will give you two rows : 
meta_key="_wp_attached_file" will give url
meta_key="_wp_attachment_metadata" will give meta info like size etc

Hope this helps better

Comment: this is how to get the thumbnail from within wordpress. I'm looking to find it from an external (non-wordpress) website by directly querying the database.

Comment: The easiest would be to query the database for the thumb url, then put it into a php var and call it in the html.
<img src="<?php echo $thumbUrl ?>" />

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to pick up thumbnail url with other post data in one select query.

You need to create special function onetime:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `get_post_thumbnail`(`incoming_post_id` INT)
    RETURNS TINYTEXT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    set @src:=null;
    set @thumb_id:=null;

    SELECT 
        meta_value into @thumb_id
    FROM 
        wp_postmeta 
    WHERE 
        `post_id` = incoming_post_id 
        AND 
        meta_key='_thumbnail_id';


    SELECT 
        guid into @src
    FROM 
        wp_posts 
    WHERE 
        ID = @thumb_id;


    return @src;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
select get_post_thumbnail(wp_posts.ID) as "thumbnail_url" from wp_posts where wp_posts.ID = 1
```

i hope that this solution will be useful for somebody.

Comment: Haven't you made it a little harder than it should be?You can do the same with a select from posts join with meta and join again with posts to get the thumbnail post

Answer (score 1):

The exact query that worked for me is:

```
select meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and post_id =  
  (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
  WHERE post_id=$postId AND 
  meta_key='_thumbnail_id' )
```

Where $postId is the id of your post. Note: You need to add the full path to your uploads folder