# Find smallest thumbnail in WordPress mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a PHP code that fetches a thumbnail from the WordPress mySQL database.

There is already a **post id** value in the code which is used to grab **meta_value** in the table **wp_postmeta**. Finally i get the thumbnail url in the **guid** column of **wp_posts**

```
SELECT meta_value,guid 
FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.meta_value=wp_posts.ID 
WHERE post_id=:id AND meta_key='_thumbnail_id' LIMIT 1
```

Everything works great, EXCEPT that its always the original uploaded image which is sometimes megabytes in size. I only need a 150x150 thumbnail which i see is an actual option in **wp-admin -> settings -> media**

Where can i grab the smallest version of the thumbnail? I assume that its already created by WordPress

Comment: maybe this answer helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974489/how-to-get-thumbnail-from-a-wordpress-database-into-an-external-page