# How to get post title, description and image in single query

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I need to fetch title, description(content) and image from wp_posts and wp_postmeta table.

I am able to fetch image using below query but not able to get the title and content.

```
SELECT childpost.* 
FROM wp_jtgw_posts childpost 
INNER JOIN wp_jtgw_postmeta parentmeta ON (childpost.ID=parentmeta.meta_value)
WHERE parentmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' 
AND parentmeta.post_id=xxxx;
```

Can anybody tell me how can i fetch title and content along with image?

Comment: Do you have to use mysql? I think it would be easier to fetch the post object using php.

Comment: I need to make api but first i need query for it, right?

Comment: Why don't you use WP_Query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/?

Comment: Looks like the answers below have you on the right path but I'll add my twopence anyway. Wordpress has a built in API. So if you want to fetch a post you can just make a request to your-site/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. See more here... http://v2.wp-api.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this (judging from the [Wordpress schema documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description))

```
SELECT
    post.id,
    post.post_content,
    post.post_title,
    thumbnail_url.meta_value as thumbnails_url
FROM
    wp_jtgw_posts as post
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_jtgw_postmeta as thumbnail ON
        post.ID = thumbnail.post_id AND
        thumbnail.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wb_jtgw_postmeta as thumbnail_url ON
        thumbnail.meta_value = thumbnail_url.post_id AND
        thumbnail_url.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
WHERE
    post.ID=xxxx;
```

I have updated the answer to go back into the `_postmeta` table with a second LEFT OUTER JOIN to pull the thumbnail_url (`meta key = '_wb_attached_file'`) for the post_id that correlates to the `thumbnail_id` found in the first LEFT OUTER JOIN to the `_postmeta` table.

Comment: i need image url... above query gave me content,title and meta_value.  I need image url instead of meta_value

Comment: Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974489/how-to-get-thumbnail-from-a-wordpress-database-into-an-external-page) as a guide I have updated the answer to go back into the `_postmeta` table and pull the url for the thumbnail_id retrieved in the first join to `_postmeta`.

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out how to use WordPress's api for this query. Your table names in this query, for example, vary from WordPress installation to installation.

But in the meantime you need to use the key/value pattern for this query.

```
SELECT childpost.title, childpost.description, img.meta_value AS img
  FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta img ON wp_posts.ID = img.post_id AND img.meta_key='_thumbnail_id'
```

The trick is to define the desired key as part of the ON clause, not define it in a WHERE clause. Using LEFT JOIN will get you the post even when the meta value you want is missing.